# html email form needing variable recipients

Tags: html, forms, email

I am trying to create some **HTML** that will send an email to a variable recipient address. My current **HTML** runs successfully on the server side which is fine, but it is relying on a fixed email recipient address. I don't want this - I want a variable email recipient address where the addressee details are entered on the form.

The Server side support team have informed that I need to use **Javascript** to retrieve the variable details that need to go into the email address (identified as "!!!! Variable!!!@coke.com" in the HTML below).

Can anyone provide any guidance on how to do this? This is for an intranet site. I'm not wanting to validate what is entered by the user, however if I can add a fixed CC address this would be useful.

The HTML is as below.

Thanks in advance,

Steve

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]>
<html class="ie ie6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
   <![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 7 ]>
   <html class="ie ie7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
      <![endif]-->
      <!--[if IE 8 ]>
      <html class="ie ie8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
         <![endif]-->
         <!--[if IE 9 ]>
         <html class="ie ie9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
            <![endif]-->
            <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
               <!--<![endif]-->
               <head>
                  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                  <title>Form Test</title>
                  <link href="/homepage/survey/Coke-new/css/base.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                  <!-- Do not edit the base file, use custom.css -->
                  <link href="/homepage/survey/Coke-new/css/custom.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                  <!-- Your customisations go here -->
                  <script src="/stylesheets/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                  <link href="/online/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                  <script src="/homepage/survey/Coke-new/js/library.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>
                  <script type="text/javascript" src="/stylesheets/misc.js"></script>
                  <!-- navigation menu style -->
               </head>
               <body>
                  <!-- Accessibility Skip To -->
                  <ul id="skip" class="visuallyhidden">
                     <!-- <li><a href="#left-nav">Skip to navigation</a></li>  Use when leftCol is in use -->
                     <li><a href="#body-content">Skip to content</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <!-- End Accessibility Skip To -->
                  <div id="top-band">
                     <!-- DHS Global Navigation -->
                     <!-- End Global Navigation -->
                  </div>
                  <div id="bodyWrap">
                     <div class="page">
                        <!-- Header Section including Logo, Narrow Colour Band and Utilities Navigation -->
                        <div class="head clearfix">
                           <!-- Program Logo -->
                           <div id="Coke-logo">
                              <a href="/">Coke logo</a>
                           </div>
                           <!-- End Program Logo -->
                           <!-- Utilities Navigation -->
                           <!--End Utilities Navigation -->
                           <!-- Application Name -->
                           <div id="app-title">
                              <span>Form Examples</span>
                           </div>
                           <!-- End Application Name -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Header section -->
                        <!-- Content section including Body Content, left and right columns -->
                        <div class="body">
                           <!-- Section containing main website content -->
                           <!-- Left Column class="leftCol" -->
                           <!-- End Left Column -->
                           <!-- Right Column class="rightCol" -->
                           <!-- End Right Column -->
                           <div class="main" id="body-content">
                              <!-- Start of actual page content -->
                              <h1>Form Examples</h1>
                              <script language="javascript"> 
                                 function replaceNewLines2(newChar)

                                                {

                                                               if (!newChar) { var newChar = " "; }



                                                               var allTextAreas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");

                                                               alert("TA L "+ allTextAreas.length);

                                                               for (var i = 0; i < allTextAreas.length; i++)

                                                                              {              

                                                                                             allTextAreas[i].value = allTextAreas[i].value.replace(/[\n]/g, newChar);                          

                                                                              }

                                                }




                              </script>              
                              <h2 class="h3">Example 1 - Stacked form fields in 1 column</h2>
                              <div id="ValidateFail" class="error-box hidden"><strong>At least one of the required fields in this form has not been completed</strong>.</div>
                              <form action="/cgi-bin/feedback" method="post" name="dummyform1" id="dummyform1" class="vertical-form" onsubmit="return validateStacked();" >
                                 <input type="hidden" name="email" value="!!!! Variable!!!@coke.com" />
                                 <!--input type="hidden" name="tfile" value="/homepage/survey/Coke-new/test.csv" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="csv" value="1" /--->
                                 <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Form Feedback" />
                                 <!--output can only be a intranet page, use the redirect meta tag in the thankyou page to redirect user to COKE -->
                                 <input type="hidden" name="output" value="/homepage/survey/Coke-new/thankyou.html" />   
                                 <div>
                                    <label for="dummy0">Text input - no width specified</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="dummy0" id="dummy0"  />
                                 </div>
                                 <div>
                                    <label for="dummy1">Text input - with required field <span class="required">(required)</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" name="dummy1" id="dummy1" />
                                    <div class="warninginfo hidden" id="dummy1Val">TExt input required</div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div>
                                    <label for="dummy2">Text input - size = 10 characters</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="dummy2" id="dummy2" size="10" />
                                 </div>
                                 <div>
                                    <label for="dummy3">Text input <span class="label-info-box"> class = size1of2 (50&#37; width of container)</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" name="dummy3" id="dummy3" class="size1of2" />               
                                 </div>
                                 <div>
                                    <label for="dummy4">Text input - class = size1of1 (100&#37; width of container)</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="dummy4" id="dummy4" class="size1of1" />
                                 </div>
                                 <div>
                                    <label for="dummy5">Textarea <span class="required">(required)</span></label><br />
                                    <textarea name="dummy5" id="dummy5" rows="5" cols="40" ></textarea>
                                    <div class="warninginfo hidden" id="dummy5Val">TExt input required</div>
                                 </div>
                                 <fieldset class="inline">
                                    <legend>Radio buttons with inline inputs - contained in a fieldset </legend>
                                    <input type="radio" id="example11" name="name11" />
                                    <label for="example11">Radio option one</label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="example12" name="name11" />
                                    <label for="example12">Radio option two</label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="example13" name="name11" />
                                    <label for="example13">Radio option three</label>
                                 </fieldset>
                                 <fieldset>
                                    <legend>Radio buttons with seperate line inputs - contained in a fieldset <span class="required">(required)</span></legend>
                                    <div id="radioValDiv">
                                       <div class="inline">
                                          <input type="radio" name="example21" id="example21"/>
                                          <label for="example21">Radio option one</label>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="inline">
                                          <input type="radio" name="example21" id="example22"/>
                                          <label for="example22">Radio option two</label>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="inline">
                                          <input type="radio" name="example21" id="example23"/>
                                          <label for="example23">Radio option three</label>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </fieldset>
                                 <div class="warninginfo hidden" id="example21Val">Select Radio button</div>
                                 <div id="example31Div">
                                    <fieldset class="inline">
                                       <legend>Checkbox with inline inputs - contained in a fieldset <span class="required">(required)</span></legend>
                                       <input type="checkbox" id="example31" name="name31" value="name31a"/>
                                       <label for="example31">Check option one</label>
                                       <input type="checkbox" id="example32" name="name31" value="name31b"/>
                                       <label for="example32">Check option two</label>
                                       <input type="checkbox" id="example33" name="name31" value="name31c"/>
                                       <label for="example33">Check option three</label>
                                    </fieldset>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="warninginfo hidden" id="example31Val">Select a Check box</div>
                                 <div>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn-primary" />
                                    <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn-reg"  onclick="window.location.reload();"/>
                                 </div>
                              </form>
                           </div>
                           <!-- end body-content -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- end Content section -->
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- end bodywrap -->
                  <!-- Page footer containing wide colour-band and footer links -->
                  <!-- Footer section -->
                  <div class="foot clearfix">
                     <div class="dhs-program-band">
                        <span class="prg-1"></span>
                        <span class="prg-2"></span>
                        <span class="prg-3"></span>
                        <span class="prg-4"></span>
                        <span class="prg-5"></span>
                        <span class="prg-6"></span>
                        <span class="prg-7"></span>
                        <span class="prg-8"></span>
                        <span class="prg-9"></span>
                        <span class="prg-10"></span>
                        <span class="prg-11"></span>
                        <span class="prg-12"></span>
                        <span class="prg-13"></span>
                        <span class="prg-14"></span>
                        <span class="prg-15"></span>
                        <span class="prg-16"></span>
                        <span class="prg-17"></span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="page">
                        <ul id="footer-nav">
                           <li class="last">
                              <a href="/">Coke Intranet</a>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div id="unity-star">Coke</div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- end Footer section -->
                  <!-- Call Javascript before closing body tag: See http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html -->
               </body>
            </html>
```

==========================================

So, therefore... just trying to work out where to add these code snipperts... Is this what I need to change?

```
    BEFORE
    <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
       <!--<![endif]-->

    AFTER
    <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">


    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers

    $headers .= 'Cc: check@coke.com . "\r\n";

    mail($_POST['email'], "subject", "message", $headers);

    <!--<![endif]-->
```

Then for the second part, do I replace:

```
    BEFORE:
    <script language="javascript"> 
      function replaceNewLines2(newChar)

    AFTER:
   <script language="javascript"> 
   if (isset($_POST['email'@coke.com]) && filter_var ($_POST'email'@coke.com],                FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  echo "email valid";!
   $email = $_POST['email'@coke.com];

   }else{ echo "email not valid"; $email = "check@coke.com"; } 

   function  replaceNewLines2(newChar)
```

Does the added code need a function header?

More questions:

Will the $_POST display a popup window asking for the name to be entered? Can I add a tag to this popup so people will know why it is asking for an email address?

What happens with the code "value="!!!! Variable!!!@coke.com" /" Do I just remove this reference?

Still very puzzled....

Comment: What I do for this sort of thing is provide a drop down list with the form that lists the possible recipients. Whichever recipient is chosen by the user determines the `to` address of the email.

Answer (score 0):

In you [PHP mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) you should use $_POST['email'] as the first parameter like this: `mail($_POST['email'], "subject", "message");`
If you need a CC address, you can use the fourth optional parameter which can include additional headers.

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($_POST['email'], "subject", "message", $headers);
```

You have to validate the user input to make sure it is a valid email address.
Small example:

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "email valid";!
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}else{
    echo "email not valid";
    $email = "your-email@mail.com";
}
```

Comment: It's not usually the best idea to pull anything from `$_GET` or `$_POST` without a little error/security checking first...

Comment: I know, it is just an simple example of how to send a mail with the variable from his form.